# 'result should have length 3': How does the ScalaTest DSL work?

Tags: scala, dsl, scalatest

ScalaTest allows you to write code like:

```
result should have length 3
```

What's going on under the hood to make this parse? Is it just using the infix notation, i.e. is it

```
result.should(have).length(3)
```

through some magic involving implicits? Or is there something more complex going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exactly right: it's magic with implicits + infix syntax.

Let's take your example apart. In

```
result should have length 3
```

the expression `result` (usually) does not have the method `should`. However, if you mixin [Matchers](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Matchers), then you get the implicit conversion `convertToAnyShouldWrapper`, which returns an [AnyShouldWrapper](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Matchers$AnyShouldWrapper). This `AnyShouldWrapper` now has an overloaded method `should`.

One of the versions of `should` takes a [HaveWord](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.words.HaveWord) as argument, and returns a weird thing called [ResultOfHaveWordForExtent](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.Matchers$ResultOfHaveWordForExtent). The `ResultOfHaveWordForExtent` now has a `length` method, which takes a `Long`, and finally returns an [Assertion](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.0/index.html#org.scalatest.package@Assertion=org.scalatest.compatible.Assertion).

Thus, your statement is desugared into:

```
convertToAnyShouldMatcher(result).should(have).length(3)
```

Notice that the method calls and arguments alternate in this chain. So in case you are not sure whether it's something like `should be` or `shouldBe`, just count the expressions, and look whether the next argument you want to supply is in an odd or an even position.